# Get all items from table with Table query Boto3 Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to get all items in sorted by date order from DynamoDB table. Scan() doesn`t provide sorting ability. Query() does provide sorting ability, but I cannot figure out how to get all table items. E.g In SQL it would be wildcard "*" to match items. What would be equivalent for DynamoDB query to match all items?

Current table is small so I can use Scan() and sort withing application. However, it is not optimal solution for my next endpoint that will need to get paginated list of items sorted by datetime from very large table.
I would appreciate any pointers how to achieve the task. Thank you